# Slicing a string repeatedly

Tags: python

Repeated slicing works on tuples and lists just fine:

```
>>> tuple = ("nav", "yad")
>>> tuple[0]
'nav'
>>> tuple[0][0]
'n'
```

But with strings:

```
>>> name="university"
>>> name[0]
'u'
```

The weird thing here is, when I try repeated slicing over string name variable,
there is nothing at `name[0][0]` or `name[0][-1]`, so why does it show `"u"`?

```
>>> name[0][0]
'u'
>>> name[0][-1]
'u'
```

And if something is at `name[0][0]` then why not on other indexes?

```
>>> name[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Repeated slicing is not a feature of lists. Try `[1,2,3][0][0]`.

Comment: Because when indexing (not slicing actually from the examples I gather) strings you get strings - a character is a string of length one in python. Type doesn't change. Not the case with tuples / lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

String is a sequence.  String of one character is still a sequence with one element.  So with a string you can do `name[0][0][0][0]...` and it will work fine.  Same with index `-1`, that returns last element of a sequence:

```
>>> name[0][0]
'u'
>>> name[0][0][-1]
'u'
>>> name[0][0][-1][-1]
'u'
```

`name[0][1]` obviously fails because there is only one element in the string `name[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Roman's answer. I think you are under the impression that `name[0]` will return some sort of `char`. But It doesn't. What happens is `name[0]` returns a string of length `1`. so no matter how many times you repeatedly index a non empty string with 0, it always returns the same.